# How to prove that two set are diffeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth map, and $F:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=f(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})-x_n$. How to prove that $F^{-1}(0)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Actually, I can prove that $F^{-1}(0) $ is a regular level set and thus a $n-1$ dimension submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can I conclude directly that $F^{-1}(0)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Or more generally, I want to prove $SU(2)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3$. It follows directly that $SU(2)$ is a Lie group of dimension $3$. Is this enough to show the diffeomorphism?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To prove two _smooth manifolds_ are diffeomorphic it suffices to construct a diffeomorphism (smooth bijection with smooth inverse) between them. In both examples mentioned this is straightforward...?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I am trying to figure out some tricky for more complicated problem. But failed. Still appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to show that
$$\begin{align*}g:&\,F^{-1}(0)=\{(x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_n):f(x_1,..,x_{n-1})=x_n\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\\&(x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_n)\mapsto (x_1,...,x_{n-1})
\end{align*}$$
is a diffeomorphism.